# How to display on Web-page elements of sub-collection for chosen collection item?

Tags: java, jsp, web

can you give idea how to display on Web-page elements of subcollection for choosen collection item? For example collection element Vegetables correspond to Carrots, Tomatoes, Onions etc. In another words A contains types of product, each element of collection A correspond to elements in collection B.
Are there some standard components or another solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use jstl tags.  Here is a [quick reference guide](http://cs.roosevelt.edu/eric/books/JSP/jstl-quick-reference.pdf) to get you started and and here is an example:

```
<c:forEach items="${vegetables}" var="vegetable"> 
      <c:forEach items="${vegetable.carrots}" var="carrot"> 
            <ul>
                <li>${carrot.color}</li>
                <li>${carrot.size}</li>
                <li>${carrot.somethingElse}</li>
            </ul>
    </c:forEach>
      <c:forEach items="${vegetable.tomatoes}" var="tomatoe"> 
            <ul>
                <li>${tomatoe.color}</li>
                <li>${tomatoe.size}</li>
                <li>${tomatoe.somethingElse}</li>
            </ul>
    </c:forEach>
      <c:forEach items="${vegetable.onions}" var="onion"> 
            <ul>
                <li>${onion.color}</li>
                <li>${onion.size}</li>
                <li>${onion.somethingElse}</li>
            </ul>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```